# diffuse lighting shader in OpenGL ES on android not wroking

Tags: android, opengl-es, lighting

i just spend my whole day trying to figur out, how to get diffuse lighting in opengl to run. for some reason, my model aka a simple cube just stays completely black, when i use the diffuse Shader. this is the VertexShader(just ignore the lines until gl_Position, those are for my own projektion algotythm and the only important things in here are the v_Position the v_Normal, which are basicly just the position and the normal after all the transforms like for example rotation):

```
#version 300 es
in vec3 aPos;
in vec3 normal; 
uniform vec4 vm;
uniform vec4 aColor;

out vec3 v_Position;
out vec4 v_Color;
out vec3 v_Normal;

void main()
{
vec3 lightPos = vec3(2.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);

float x2 = (aPos.x * cos(vm.y) - (aPos.z) * sin(vm.y));
float z2 = ((aPos.x * sin(vm.y) + (aPos.z) * cos(vm.y))) + 7.0f;

float y2 = (aPos.y * cos(vm.z) - (z2 - 7.0f) * sin(vm.z));
float z3 = ((aPos.y * sin(vm.z) + (z2 - 7.0f) * cos(vm.z))) + 7.0f;

float nx2 = (normal.x * cos(vm.y) - (normal.z) * sin(vm.y));
float nz2 = ((normal.x * sin(vm.y) + (normal.z) * cos(vm.y))) + 7.0f;

float ny2 = (normal.y * cos(vm.z) - (nz2 - 7.0f) * sin(vm.z));
float nz3 = ((normal.y * sin(vm.z) + (nz2 - 7.0f) * cos(vm.z))) + 7.0f;

float dst = sqrt((x2 * x2) + (y2 * y2) + (z3 * z3));

gl_Position = vec4(x2 / z3 * vm.x,y2 / z3 * vm.x  * vm.w, dst * 0.0001,1.0f);

v_Position = vec3(x2, y2, z3);
v_Color = aColor;
v_Normal = vec3(nx2, ny2, nz3);
}
```

this is the FragmentShader :

```
#version 300 es

precision mediump float;
uniform vec3 u_LightPos;

in vec3 v_Position;
in vec4 v_Color;
in vec3 v_Normal;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
float distance = length(vec3(u_LightPos) - v_Position);
vec3 lightVector = normalize(vec3(u_LightPos) - v_Position);
float diffuse = max(dot(v_Normal, lightVector), 0.1);
diffuse = diffuse * (1.0 / (1.0 + (0.25 * distance * distance)));
FragColor = vec4(vec3(v_Color) * (diffuse), 1.0f);
}
```

for u_LightPos i passed in 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
for aColor : 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f

in case it helps, this is my vertexBuffer(the stride is 6 and the first three floats are for position the next three for the normals) :

```
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
             0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
             0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
             0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,

            -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
             0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
             0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
             0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,

            -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

             0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
             0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
             0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
             0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
             0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
             0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
             0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
             0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
             0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,

            -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
             0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
             0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
             0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but i yeeted out everything which had something to do with u_LightPos and now it works